# django multiple user registration

Tags: python, django, registration

Here is my Model

```
class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser):
username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True) # What goes here ??

USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'


class Hotel(BaseUser):
  hotel_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  url = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  is_hotel = models.BooleanField(default=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.hotel_name


class Customer(BaseUser):
  f_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  l_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.f_name
```

And here is my admin.py

```
class HotelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('hotel_name',)

  fieldsets = (
    ('Hotel info', {
      'fields': ('username', 'password1', 'password2')
    }),

  )

search_fields = ('username',)



class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('f_name',)

admin.site.register(Hotel, HotelAdmin)
admin.site.register(Customer, CustomerAdmin)
```

Here what I want is Hotel and Customer can register.

I want to use AbstractUser but I dont know how to do that ?  In the admin side I want that even admin can add them manually.

Any help ??

Comment: sorry the formatting went wrong

Comment: pls read first the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Comment: I read it but dont know what to do with this ??

Comment: just "jump into water", then you will learn how to "swim"